# Use NOT IN keyword after joining two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to use a query that first identifies a list of customers that DO have an invoice and then uses that list to identify the ones 
that DO NOT have an invoice. I must use the NOT IN keyword.

The following is the SQL code for each table:

```
    CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER ( 
CUS_CODE        NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
CUS_LNAME       VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
CUS_FNAME       VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
CUS_INITIAL     CHAR(1), 
CUS_AREACODE CHAR(3) DEFAULT '615' NOT NULL CHECK(CUS_AREACODE IN ('615','713','931')), 
CUS_PHONE       CHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
CUS_BALANCE     NUMBER(9,2) DEFAULT 0.00, 
CONSTRAINT CUS_UI1 UNIQUE(CUS_LNAME,CUS_FNAME))

CREATE TABLE INVOICE ( 
INV_NUMBER NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
CUS_CODE NUMBER NOT NULL REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUS_CODE), 
INV_DATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT INV_CK1 CHECK (INV_DATE > TO_DATE('01-JAN-2012','DD-MON-YYYY')))
```

select * from customer results in:

[image]

select * from invoice results in:

[image]

I'm not really sure on how to get started.

Thanks

The answer gives:

[image]

Comment: Can you at least show us sample data which would demonstrate the logic behind your query?  This would also help us to make suggestions.

Comment: what is the problem to use it?

Comment: I added the results of select * from customer; and select * from invoice; above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just get all the rows in `CUSTOMER` where there is no record in `INVOICE`:

```
SELECT * FROM customer c
 WHERE c.cus_code NOT IN ( SELECT i.cus_code FROM invoice i );
```

An anti-join might be more efficient here, however:

```
SELECT * FROM customer c
 WHERE c.cus_code NOT IN ( SELECT i.cus_code FROM invoice i
                            WHERE i.cus_code = c.cus_code );
```

**EDIT**: See [**SQL Fiddle here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/585f5/1) - I added an `ORDER BY` clause to match the desired result given above.

Comment: Do you mean, they return incorrect results, or do you mean, they are not correct as in they don't follow directions?

Comment: They return the incorrect results. I have provided the desired result in a photo above.

Comment: They do not return incorrect results - please see SQL Fiddle here (I added an `ORDER BY` to make things clearer): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/585f5/1

Comment: SELECT cus_fname, cus_lname 
FROM customer c
 WHERE c.cus_code NOT IN ( SELECT i.cus_code FROM invoice i )
 order by cus_fname asc; This gives the correct results. Whoops, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE CUS_CODE NOT IN (SELECT CUS_CODE FROM INVOICE)
```

Comment: @Boognish I don't understand how it isn't correct. Per your screenshot that is the list of customers that have no invoices.

Comment: You were correct, sorry. To clean it up more, SELECT cus_fname, cus_lname
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE CUS_CODE NOT IN (SELECT CUS_CODE FROM INVOICE)
order by cus_fname; was what I needed.